# Erasure Coded Pool suggested PG count

Tags: ceph, cephfs

I'm messing around with pg calculator to figure out the best pg count for my cluster. I have an erasure coded FS pool which will most likely use half space of the cluster in the forseeable future. But the pg calculator only has options for replicated pools. Should i just type according to the erasure-code ratio for replica # or is there another way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From Ceph Nautilus version onwards there's a pg-autoscaler that does the scaling for you. You just need to create a pool with an initial (maybe low) value. As for the calculation itself your assumption is correct, you take the number of chunks into account when planning the pg count.

Answer (score 0):

From :

[redhat docs:](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_ceph_storage/4/html/storage_strategies_guide/placement_groups_pgs#pg-count-for-small-clusters)

3.3.4. Calculating PG Count
If you have more than 50 OSDs, we recommend approximately 50-100 placement groups per OSD to balance out resource usage, data durability and distribution. If you have less than 50 OSDs, choosing among the PG Count for Small Clusters is ideal. For a single pool of objects, you can use the following formula to get a baseline:

```
                (OSDs * 100)
   Total PGs =  ------------
                 pool size
```

Where pool size is either the number of replicas for replicated pools or the K+M sum for erasure coded pools (as returned by ceph osd erasure-code-profile get).

You should then check if the result makes sense with the way you designed your Ceph cluster to maximize data durability, data distribution and minimize resource usage.

The result should be rounded up to the nearest power of two. Rounding up is optional, but recommended for CRUSH to evenly balance the number of objects among placement groups.

For a cluster with 200 OSDs and a pool size of 3 replicas, you would estimate your number of PGs as follows:

```
  (200 * 100)
   ----------- = 6667. Nearest power of 2: 8192
        3
```

With 8192 placement groups distributed across 200 OSDs, that evaluates to approximately 41 placement groups per OSD. You also need to consider the number of pools you are likely to use in your cluster, since each pool will create placement groups too. Ensure that you have a reasonable maximum PG count.